# Cross compiling OpenSSL - openssl binary cannot be executed

Tags: c, openssl, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile OpenSSL for PowerPC with the FIPS module. My build host's architecture is not PowerPC. I was able to cross compile the FIPS module just fine. However, when I run make on openssl, during the linking phase, it tries to execute certain binaries to run tests. The issue is that those binaries are produced for the target architecture and, as a result, I get the error "cannot execute binary file". Is there a way to produce executables of these tests on the host architecture rather than the target architecture? Should I be handling this process differently? Here are the following commands I used to build openssl. I replaced certain directories with DIR_HIDDEN.

```
export FIPS_DIRECTORY="$PWD/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e/"
export cross="DIR_HIDDEN/powerpc-linux-gnu-"
make clean  || exit 1
make dclean || exit 1
./Configure --prefix=$PWD/../tgt/linux-ppc603e linux-ppc fips --with-fipsdir=${FIPS_DIRECTORY}
make depend  || exit 1
make CC="$FIPS_DIRECTORY/bin/fipsld" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib" AR="${cross}ar r" LD="$FIPS_DIRECTORY/bin/fipsld" FIPSLD_CC="${cross}gcc" HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" || exit 1
make install || exit 1
```

I get the following error during the make command:

```
shlib_target=; if [ -n "" ]; then \
            shlib_target="linux-shared"; \
    elif [ -n "libcrypto" ]; then \
      FIPSLD_CC="/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e//bin/fipsld"; CC=/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e//bin/fipsld; export CC FIPSLD_CC; \
    fi; \
    LIBRARIES="-L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto" ; \
    make -f ../Makefile.shared -e \
            APPNAME=openssl OBJECTS="openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o" \
            LIBDEPS=" $LIBRARIES -ldl" \
            link_app.${shlib_target}
make[2]: Entering directory `/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/apps'
( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto -ldl}"; LDCMD="${LDCMD:-/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e//bin/fipsld}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DB_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -I/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e//include -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DAES_ASM}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do echo $x; done | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:=openssl} openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o ${LIBDEPS} )
/DIR_HIDDEN/openssl/openssl-1.0.1i/../../openssl-fips/tgt/linux-ppc603e//bin/fipsld: line 185: ./openssl: cannot execute binary file
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 126
```

When invoking the make command again and again, I get the same error but for all the applications located in the /test directory of the openssl tarball. Examples include bntest, ectest, and ecdhtest.

I received a similar error when I was cross compiling the FIPS module, but I was able to resolve that by including the host compiler in the HOSTCC variable. A similar trick did not work for the openssl compilation.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ssl needs to be damn sure that the host's math libraries are working properly. running the tests on an x86 system and passing is pointless if you're going to be running the binaries on an ARM box. "gee, this was legal in Thailand. Why am I being arrested in the USA?"

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I've seen that the typical workflow is that the tests are executed on the target machine. However, is there a way that I can get cross compilation not to error out while allowing me to execute tests in the proper way?

Comment: might be a make target that specifies skipping the tests.

Comment: Not that I see. Plus, I would want to run these tests if possible.

Comment: *"...I get the error 'cannot execute binary file'"* - I get that too when cross compiling for android-x86 (but not android-arm). I just ignore it. I do perform `readelf -h ./libcrypto.a | grep -i 'class\|machine' | head -2` to ensure the library is the correct architecture.

Comment: @user1590960 what is your target Linux distro? Have you tried [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)?

Comment: 32-bit PowerPC 603e. I haven't looked into buildroot yet. I'll look into that.

Comment: I answered this question below, but I did take a brief look into buildroot. The only reference to FIPS and buildroot is a patch that disables FIPS support. Very encouraging...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify the make command to get the process to complete. I was missing the FIPS_SIG environment variable, which points to the incore script. The make command is now:

```
make FIPS_SIG=$PWD/`find ../../openssl-fips/ -iname incore` CC="$FIPS_DIRECTORY/bin/fipsld" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib" AR="${cross}ar r" LD="$FIPS_DIRECTORY/bin/fipsld" FIPSLD_CC="${cross}gcc"
```

I still see prints to console that indicate that openssl cannot be executed, but these are warnings and don't halt the makefile. Not really sure why or how this fixed the problem, but I'll take it.